# Count specific value up to a position in a string for each row (R)

Tags: r

I have a data frame as the below:

```
ID   | Provider | String
-----------------------
1    | A        | A, NA, NA, B, NA
2    | B        | NA, A, B, NA, NA, NA
3    | B        | B
4    | C        | C, NA, NA, A, NA, NA, C, NA
```

I'd like to count how many NA in the string after the value that matches the one in the "Provider" column up to the point of unmatched value or the end.

The desired output is

```
   ID    | Provider  | String                     | Output
    ------------------------------------------------------
    1    | A        | A, NA, NA, B, NA            | 2 
    2    | B        | NA, A, B, NA, NA, NA        | 3
    3    | B        | B                           | 0
    4    | C        | C, NA, NA, A, NA, NA, C, NA | 3
```

ID1 has a provider A and the string has two NA after A before it meets B.
ID2 has a provider B and the string has three NA after B.
ID3 has a provider B and the string has no NA after B.
ID4 has a provider C and the string has two NA after C before it meets A + one more NA after the second C.

My initial approach is to count the total NA first using tokenizer

```
df$Output0 <- sapply(df$String, function(x) sum(unlist(tokenize_words(x)) %in% c('NA')))
```

However, it returns all 0s.

How should I target the below problem?

Comment: Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Answer (score 2):

One option using regex and two functions from stringr.

```
library("data.table")
library("stringr")

DT <- data.table(
  ID = 1:3,
  Provider = c("A", "B", "C"),
  String = c("A, NA, NA, B, NA", "NA, A, B, NA, NA, NA", "C, NA, NA, A, NA, NA, C, NA")
)

DT[, Output := sum(str_count(
  str_extract_all(String, paste0(Provider, "(, NA)*"), simplify = TRUE),
  "NA")), 
  by = ID
]

DT
   ID Provider                      String Output
1:  1        A            A, NA, NA, B, NA      2
2:  2        B        NA, A, B, NA, NA, NA      3
3:  3        C C, NA, NA, A, NA, NA, C, NA      3
```

Comment: Thank you.  How does "simplify = TRUE" work in the above code?

Comment: 'str_extract_all' will return a list for the result instead of a vector if you don't add that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `regmatches` + `gregexpr`

```
df$Output0 <- apply(
    df,
    1,
    function(x) sum(unlist(gregexpr("NA", toString(unlist(regmatches(x[3], gregexpr(sprintf("%s(, NA)+", x[2]), x[3])))))) > 0)
)
```

such that

```
> df
  ID Provider                      String Output0
1  1        A            A, NA, NA, B, NA       2
2  2        B        NA, A, B, NA, NA, NA       3
3  3        B                           B       0
4  4        C C, NA, NA, A, NA, NA, C, NA       3
```

**Data**

```
df <- 
structure(list(ID = 1:4, Provider = c("A", "B", "B", "C"), String = c("A, NA, NA, B, NA",
"NA, A, B, NA, NA, NA", "B", "C, NA, NA, A, NA, NA, C, NA")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. I have a small question. Why should the first code need ">0" at the end?

Comment: @duyzero123 It is because `gregexpr` will return `0` if it doesn't find matched pattern. `>0` can interpret it as the found matched patterns in terms of logic values